# jQuery can't alert anything or redirect inside an plugin's callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jquery-callback

I use a plugin to upload images which is working fine, the code is:

```
$('input[name=photo]').change(function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];

    $.canvasResize(file, {
        width: 600,
        height: 500,
        crop: false,
        quality: 90,
        callback: function(data, width, height) {

            if(width > 100)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                alert("this is not an image"); // this isn't working
                return false;
            }

            var fd = new FormData();
            var f = $.canvasResize('dataURLtoBlob', data);
            f.name = file.name;
            fd.append($('input[name=photo]').attr('name'), f);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'doupload.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: fd,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function() {
                    window.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"; // THIS ISN'T WORKING TOO
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Now after it's done I try to redirect to another page after AJAX is finished but it's not working, alerts are also not working. Any ideas?

Comment: any console errors? whats the response of AJAX
?

Comment: No errors, the response is nothing, I tried url: 'test.php', with nothing but <?php echo 'test'; ?> inside and success: function(data) {alert(data);} but it alerts nothing

Comment: so you mean `callback` function is getting called and AJAX request is also going and response is also coming even though empty.

Comment: there is no response but the images are getting uploaded fine :(

Comment: That's the plugin btw: https://github.com/gokercebeci/canvasResize

Comment: can you put alert/breakpoint at `// THIS ISN'T WORKING TOO` and see if its reaching or not. This is necessary otherwise blindly answering is of no use

Comment: No alert isn't working inside success :/

Comment: that means there is problem with the AJAX. In network tab, what do you see as response of AJAX, is it 200 status code and anything returned

Comment: I am in the network tab inside chrome console, you do mean that? But I don't know what the hell this is and I don't see any "200" :(

Comment: Is it possible to just redirect after AJAX is finished even with an "bad" success?

Comment: yes.. use `.always` see for documentation  [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I replaced success with always but it's not working, can you show me an example? I'm getting sick of all the buttugly JS syntaxes. PHP is a paraside compared to this crap...............

Comment: first javascript is not crap.. you need to read the docs carefully.. just go once through above link.. you would find the answer/examples there. replacing is not correct way

Comment: Yes ofc JS is not crap and a good website is impossible without that but the syntax is still buttugly... Replacing success with complete did the trick now. Please post an normal answer and I'll accept that. Can you maybe tell me why this plugin isn't working on mobile browser? Could it be because of AJAX?

Comment: So if its working now means simply your ajax request was resulting in error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'doupload.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: fd,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function() {
                    location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
                },
                error: function() {
                    //handle errors here
                },
                complete: function() {
                    // this code is always executed
                    location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
                }
})
```

Or

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({...
            });
jqXHR.always(function(){
      location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
})
```

Comment: "So if its working now means simply your ajax request was resulting in error." what what error? It just returns nothing but the image is uploaded successfull. It returns nothing even when inside doupload.php is nothing but a simple echo

Comment: And do you have an idea why this plugin isn't working on mobile browser?

Comment: try `error: function() {
                  alert('error')  //handle errors here
                },` in above code

Comment: dont know about the plugin, you need to see its support on their site

Comment: Ok I tried and it alerts "error" but how can I find out what kind of error?

Comment: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus ,errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); alert(errorThrown) //handle errors here }`

Comment: so the the returned response was something that is not recognisable by AJAX

Comment: I guess it's just the plugin, because I tried it just with echo 'test'; inside php file

Comment: try `echo "{\"errmessage\":\"$errmessage\"}";` , plugin has no relation to it, its your server side problem

Comment: I removed       dataType: 'json', and now it works only with success :D I allready wondered what json have to do with image file upload anyway, thanks again

Comment: its related to the format of response that browser is expecting from server. and valid one is as given above

Comment: Oh ok now I know why it still not work on mobile browser.. thanks